# Kendo grid update field summary after change of cell value

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, summary

I have a kendo grid  with summary footers for some columns  of the grid. When I a get datasource values from server summaries are displayed correctly. But when I change the value of a cell of a column that has summary the summary is not updated immediately. I would to ask how can I achieve immediate update of footer summaries.

Thank you

Comment: It would be great if you update your code in the question.

Comment: Lets see the code. Controller and view